# How to Store SMTP Credentials in Android App?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Android app that periodically sends an email using MailKit. My question is, what's the best approach to storing credentials for the "service account" that sends the messages?

I'm using my own Gmail account credentials, but have concerns about storing them in the app itself (security and if the password needs to be reset).

I'm expecting some backlash over the approach in general, so if there is a completely different way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks

```
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test Email", "noreply@nowhere.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Me", "myemailuser@gmail.com"));
        message.Subject = "Test Email";
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = "Test Body"
        };

        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            smtpClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smtpClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            smtpClient.Authenticate("myemailuser", "mypassword");
            smtpClient.Send(message);
            smtpClient.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

Comment: Don't do it. Someone (with some effort) can get those credentials. Store them in a server and then create something like a rest endpoint (with authentication like an api key).

Comment: @Salem Don't you still have to store the API key and secret in the app?

Comment: I second the "don't do it". If you store the id/pwd in code, your Google account would be owned the minute the ipa is downloaded. Personally I would just not send blind email from within app, I would OAuth2 to an https endpoint and post the message to it and have the server send it....

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, but once again in order to use OAuth2 you need credentials, right?

Comment: @user2966445 OAuth2 **Implicit flow** does not require a user secret to be used, this is used by lots of services/APIs (i.e. Facebook, MS, Google, etc,,,) and is a forced requirement by most,  so that you do not have to store anything on the client other than a client identifier and no client secret.  (i.e. Facebook only allows server-based apps/services to contain the *secret* for logging in to their services, and clients to use an id via implicit flow) This is a good blog article explaining how it works: http://labs.hybris.com/2012/06/05/oauth2-the-implicit-flow-aka-as-the-client-side-flow/

Comment: @SushiHangover This looks like a front-end flow where the user is already logged in to a site and sees the "authorization" screen to proceed. I'm looking for a backend (behind-the-scenes) solution where an app talks to an API without the user knowing.

Comment: @user2966445 if the *user* never *logins* into to anything (your service, a 3rd party service (Facebook, G+, MS, Azure AD, etc...) , than you can use certificate pinning to enforce a https connection to an endpoint that only allows a client with that cert to attach... no client secrets, no MITM issue, etc... In the end, the issue will always be if an app contains a hard-coded secret than other security is moot...

Comment: @user2966445 I've seen app scanners that download apps 24/7 from the app stores and do nothing but pull id/pwd from code. Lucky this was in a professional security environment, but the toolset was actually bought from a hacker group that uses this for fun/profit... :-/ In the end, it is your app/your account that could be used for whatever reason, you are the one that must decide if the risk and liability is acceptable.

Comment: @SushiHangover I guess this is way more complicated of an issue than I thought. I assumed most mobile apps call APIs behind the scenes in order to retrieve data, make updates, etc.

Comment: @user2966445 they do, mostly using SSL endpoints of course, but the security on who and/or what is allowed to make those calls to it is up to you, if you do not secure the endpoint you have to be willing to accept that it *could* be used by anyone. As a public example look at Pokemon Go, on launch they used SSL endpoints but no authorization on who could use them, they skipped any security on them, thus hundreds of hackers use that to create all those third party mapping services, disassembled the app and got the TCP Socket, http GET&POST parameters... it took them months to lock it down.. ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover Do you know what Pokemon Go uses now, in place of the compromised solution?

Comment: @user2966445 Well, they started with non-secure (HTTP!) endpoints within Google's cloud.. just crazy, lazy and/or stupid.... these were "hacked" the day of release. I, personally, have not looked recently, but what I saw on reddit they are pinning client certs now, but again I have not seen this myself, they have added `Captcha` recently to prevent bots from automating the app via Android emulators since the endpoints are not available outside the app so they are locking them down somehow.